# "СвербИло" или "свербЕло": как правильно?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, глаголы, времена

Помогите разобраться, как пишется "сверб(и/е)ло"? "Карта слов" говорит, что правильно через Е (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)), однако в "Нацкорпусе" встречаются варианты и с И (см. [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE)). Так в чём же тут подвох, может, это вообще разные слова?..

Comment: Видимо, существовало два слова свербеть и свербить. https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C. В дальнейшем все перемешалось.

Comment: Аналогично, существовало два слова скорбеть/скорбить: https://kak-pravilno.net/skorbet-ili-skorbit-kak-pravilno/#:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%C2%AB%D0%B5%C2%BB%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.

Comment: Похоже, эта привычка у всех слов с "рб"